# Filter list items after storing in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store some list item into a variable and then loop through the variable and display only the list items that have a certain data attribute. It is worth mentioning that just using a simple show/hide on the li's on the page will not work for what I'm doing. https://jsfiddle.net/0jbnLv0k/

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li data-color="blue"></li>
<li data-color="red"></li>
<li data-color="green"></li>
<li data-color="blue"></li>
<li data-color="red"></li>
<li data-color="green"></li>
</ul>

<button class="blue">blue</button>
<button class="red">red</button>
<button class="yellow">yellow</button>
```

Jquery:

```
 var items = $('ul li');
 items.remove();

 var result = $.grep(items, function(e){ return e.data == 'blue'; });
 $('ul').html('<li>' + result + '</li>');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It is worth mentioning that just using a simple show/hide on the li's on the page will not work for what I'm doing"?

Comment: If I just show and hide the list items on the page it will break my other code. I only need the green li's for example in the DOM.

Comment: you mean, if you click on the green button, you need to display only the green one's list contents. without using hide and display logic, is it so?

Comment: ameenulaa0007- that is exactly what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that

```
typeof e.data === 'undefined'
```

Solution is this:

```
var items = $('ul li');
items.remove();

var result = $.grep(items, function(e){ 
    return $(e).attr('data-color') == 'blue'; 
});
$('ul').append( result );
```

But this is very bad end expensive ( time consuming ) way to display DOM elements. Much better would be add class with

```
display: none;
```

property.

Instead all this code you can use only one line:

```
$("li:not([data-color='blue'])").addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var getClass = $(this).attr("class");
  $("ul").find("li").not("li[data-color="+getClass+"]").remove();
});
```

you could use `not` selector removing all list elements except the selected class.
https://jsfiddle.net/0jbnLv0k/5/